# applescript make skype call and play song

Tags: macos, applescript, skype

Hi I'm trying to use this script to make a phone tough skype with applescript, and play a song in itunes.

All the parts of the script works but put together it doesn't work.

I'm always getting the same error, one time it worked but couldn't replicate that.

the script is:

```
set audioFilename to "Silly_Farts-Joe-1473367952"

-- Mostly from  http://forum.skype.com/viewtopic.php?t=29120
tell application "Skype"
    send command "CALL +0112345678" script name "phoneOut"
    set calls to send command "SEARCH ACTIVECALLS" script name "phoneOut"
    set callID to last word of calls
    repeat
        set status to send command "GET CALL " & callID & " STATUS" script name "phoneOut"
        if last word of status is not "ROUTING" then exit repeat
    end repeat
    repeat
        set status to send command "GET CALL " & callID & " STATUS" script name "phoneOut"
        if last word of status is "INPROGRESS" then exit repeat
    end repeat
end tell

-- From various apple scripts
tell application "iTunes"
    activate
    tell source "Library"
        tell playlist "Library"
            set toPlay to track audioFilename
            play toPlay
        end tell
    end tell
    set trackTime to duration of toPlay
    delay trackTime
    stop
end tell

-- From those forum blokes again
tell application "Skype"
    send command "SET CALL " & callID & " STATUS FINISHED" script name "phoneOut"
end tell
```

the event log looks like this.

```
tell application "Skype"
    send command "CALL +0123456789" script name "phoneOut"
        --> "CALL 5357 STATUS UNPLACED"
    send command "SEARCH ACTIVECALLS" script name "phoneOut"
        --> "CALLS "
    send command "GET CALL CALLS STATUS" script name "phoneOut"
        --> "ERROR 11 Invalid call id"
    send command "GET CALL CALLS STATUS" script name "phoneOut"
        --> "ERROR 11 Invalid call id"
    send command "GET CALL CALLS STATUS" script name "phoneOut"
        --> "ERROR 11 Invalid call id"
    send command "GET CALL CALLS STATUS" script name "phoneOut"
        --> "ERROR 11 Invalid call id"
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay found the problem, i think SEARCH ACTIVECALLS have been removed from the api.

I found the Command SEARCH CALLS, wich gives you all the calls made, but the newest one is always the first. So this will work

```
set calls to send command "SEARCH CALLS" script name "phoneOut"
set callID to second word of calls
```